# In C, should Unit Test be written for Header file or C file

Tags: c, unit-testing, struct, tdd

I have a header file which contains declaration of struct and some methods, and a 'C' file which defines(implements) the struct and the methods. Now while writing Unit Test Cases, I need to check if some struct variable(which do not have getter methods) are modified.Since the struct's definition is contained in the C file, should the unit test cases be based on header file or C file ?

Comment: My recommendation: create unit tests based on header files.

Comment: The variables (which i want to verify in Unit Test) of the struct are only defined in the 'C file and they dont have getter methods. So is it OK if I add some methods in the header file which will be just used only for unit testing purpose ?

Comment: If the states of those `struct`s don't impact the behavior of the functions in the header file, why are those states being maintained? In other words, you shouldn't have to test the implementation details if you can test the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the interface of the component available to other parts of the system, the header in your case, and not the implementation details of the interface.

Unit tests make assertions about the behavior of a component but shouldn't depend on how that behavior is implemented. The tests describe *what* the component does, not *how* it is done. If you change your implementation but preserve the same behavior your tests should still pass.

If instead your tests depend on a specific implementation they will be brittle. Changing the implementation will require changing the tests. Not only is this extra work but it voids the reassurance the tests should offer. If you could run the existing test against the new implementation you would have some confidence that the new implementation has not changed behavior other components might depend on. Once you have to change the test to be able to run it against a new implementation you must carefully consider if you have changed any of the test's expectations in the process.

It may be important to test behavior not accessible using the public interface of this component. Consider that a good hint that this interface may not be well designed. TDD encourages a "test first" approach and this is one of the reasons why. If you start by defining the assertions you want to make about a component's behavior you must then design an interface which exposes that behavior. That is what makes the process "test driven".

If you must write tests after the component they are testing then at least try to use this opportunity to re-evaluate the design and learn from your test. Either this behavior is an implementation detail and not worth testing or else the interface should be updated to expose it (this may be more complicated than just making it public as it should also be safe and reasonable for other components of the system to access this now public attribute).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that *all* testing, other than ephemeral stuff performed by developers during the development process, should be testing the API rather than the internals. That is, after all, the specification you're required to meet.

So, if you maintain stuff that's *not* visible to the outside world, that itself is not an aspect that needs direct testing. Instead, assuming something wrong there would *affect* the outside world, it's *that* effect you should test.

Encapsulation means being free to *totally* change the underlying implementation without the outside world being affected and you'll find that, if you code your tests based on the external view, no changes will be needed if you make such a change.

So, for example, if your unit is an address book, the things you should be testing are along the lines of:

- can we insert an entry?
- can we delete it?
- can we retrieve it?
- can we insert a hundred entries and query them in random order?

It's *not* things like:

- do the structure data fields get created properly?
- is the linked list internally consistent?